# TryIsInRole Exchange 2010 Error

Tags: exchange-2010

We've recently taken on a new server (with a plan to migrate exchange to O365 ASAP), but we've encountered an error when you go to set Out Of Office via OWA. I've done some searching about but cannot find anything on this, any help would be greatly aprpeciated

```
Server Error in '/ecp' Application.
Method 'TryIsInRole' in type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ControlPanel.RecipientStatisticsReportQueryProcessor' from assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ControlPanel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Method 'TryIsInRole' in type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ControlPanel.RecipientStatisticsReportQueryProcessor' from assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ControlPanel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[TypeLoadException: Method 'TryIsInRole' in type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ControlPanel.RecipientStatisticsReportQueryProcessor' from assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ControlPanel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.]
   Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ControlPanel.RbacModule.Init(HttpApplication application) +0
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +480
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +350
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +382

[HttpException (0x80004005): Method 'TryIsInRole' in type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ControlPanel.RecipientStatisticsReportQueryProcessor' from assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ControlPanel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11432982
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +88
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4408276

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8800; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8762
```

Comment: Exchange version of Exchange 2010 please - service pack 3 I presume, with which rollup?

Comment: It seems something error in IIS, I think you could first try “iisreset” in CMD. In addition, try to update to the latest Exchange 2010 version.

Comment: Currently on rollup 20, i'll upgrade to 26 and report back, iisreset has been tried already unfortunately (after posting)

Comment: Upgrading to rollup 26 appears to have fixed the issue,